# How to disable browser respone inside iframe but not in the main page

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

How to disable browser respone inside iframe, but leaving the main page responding normally.

As seen in the picture below, this is my case, I've been trying to make the web inside the iframe unreponsive to drag-scrolling and to double-tap-zoom and stuff like that, cause my web inside the iframe will detect the position of the finger and move an object along (i.e. moving the base in arkanoid or moving one de rectangles in pong).

So far I've tried stuff like:

1)

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(evt){evt.preventDefault();}, false);
```

2)

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){return false;}, false);
```

The green area should respond, but the red one shouldn´t.

[image: Example]

Until now none of them seem to work, since still the browser responding to the input remains variable, somtimes it will stay put and drag the object inside the iframe and sometimes it will scroll the whole webpage.

I have to add that my code must be inside the iframe and not in the main webpage that contains the iframe.

Best regards.

Comment: add the sandbox attrib to the iframe to disable it's javascript.

Comment: add a div over your iframe with position absolute and display none...and then when you want  to disable it...turn the display none to display block of that div!!!

Comment: @MESSIAH I can't add a dive over the iframe, read my last line. I'm inserting my webapp in an iframe on my customer website, yet I have no control of his website, only mine.

Comment: @dandavis I need javascript.

Answer (score 3):

In the iframe you could use this css:

```
html, body {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vU4GB/1/. Works only in Firefox and Chrome though.

Comment: This seems like disables all interaction with what's inside the iframe.

Comment: @FeleMed Well yes, that's what I get from your question. You should clarify it.

Comment: I added this in my question "my web inside the iframe will detect the position of the finger and move an object along (i.e. moving the base in arkanoid or moving one de rectangles in pong)".  need to have full interaction with what's inside the iframe but the browser must not respond when the interaction comes from inside the iframe.